# Why do you left shift the quotient in this binary division case?

Tags: c, binary, integer-division

This is a problem that is nagging me for quite some time.

Consider the binary division of the number `0b10101` (21 in base 10) by the binary number `0b10` (2 in base 10). Since division by two is a right shift by one, it is obvious that the quotient (truncated) is `0b1010` !
I am trying to implement binary division in `C`
But recently, I tried to do this in pen and paper, and was perplexed to get paused along the way!

My algorithm is simple since, I align the most significant bit of the divisor with the dividend by appropriate left shift, then do the comparison to get the bit of the quotient followed by subtraction to get the next dividend for the next iteration.

We continue this Euclidean division till we get the dividend < remainder.

But,
Consider :

```
10 ) 10101 ( 101
    -10000 
     ------------
           101 
         -1000
     -------------
            101
           -100
     -------------
              1 // Why don't you stop here ? 
                       // Since at this step the dividend is less than divisor?
```

I know the above quotient obtained as a result of my faulty algorithm is wrong! The quotient should be `0b1010` !

- Why do we left shift the quotient by one ?

  - Why do we in    **essence** wait for the **bits** of the aligned
    divisor `0b10000`  to equal that of the number of **bits**  original divisor
    `0b10`, despite having successfully calculated the remainder ?

Comment: The most significant bit of the quotient is 8 since `21 / 2` is `8+2` with remainder 1. If you produce the quotient by setting the correct bit at each step of the algorithm, then you can stop as soon as you reach the remainder. But if you produce the quotient by left shifting and appending a bit, then you always need to do the correct number of left shifts (so that the MSB of the quotient is shifted to the correct place). In other words, it's because the quotient in your example has a zero at the end. The shift after finding the remainder is needed to append that zero.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Please see my edits! :)

Comment: @user3386109 Please, see my edits! Can you please clarify more?

Comment: OK, please re-add tags then

Comment: The correct condition for the second loop is `while (x >= d)`.

Comment: @user3386109 But why?

Comment: I already told you why. You need to shift the quotient until the MSB of the quotient is at the correct bit position. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My fixed solution:**

```
uint32_t divide(uint32_t y, uint32_t x, uint32_t *q)
{
    (*q) = 0;
    if (y < x)
    {
        *q = 0;
        return y;
    }
    uint32_t tq = 0;
    uint32_t td = 0;
    int shift = 0;
    while (y >= x)
    {
        shift = bitlen(y) - bitlen(x);
        tq = (1 << shift);
        td = (x << shift);
        while (y <  td)
        {
            tq >>= 1;
            td >>= 1;
        }
        
        y -= (td);
        (*q) += tq;
            
    }
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same as grade school...

```
   -------------
10 ) 10101
```

How many times does 10 go into 1?  Zero

```
     0
   -------------
10 ) 10101
```

Into 10?  1 time

```
     01
   -------------
10 ) 10101
     10
    ----
      01
```

How many times into 01? Zero times

```
     010
   -------------
10 ) 10101
     10
    ----
      010
```

How many times into 10? One time

```
     0101
   -------------
10 ) 10101
    -10
    ----
      010
      -10
      ------
        01
```

How many times into 01?  Zero times

```
     01010
   -------------
10 ) 10101
    -10
    ----
      010
      -10
      ------
        01
```

Answer: 1010 remainder 1

The big difference is in grade school you kinda needed to memorize a multiplication table, for binary it is either zero times or one time and you can essentially pattern match/greater than less than based on bits instead of having to multiply something.

### Edit

Grade school, decimal

```
   -----------
10 ) 1234

     0
   -----------
10 ) 1234
     12

     01
   -----------
10 ) 1234
     12
    -10
    ---
      23

     012x
   -----------
10 ) 1234
     12
    -10
    ---
      23
     -20
     ------
       3
```

You are telling me that in grade school you were taught to stop there and not fill in all the spots above the numerator?  You left the ones column dangling like that? Unfilled? Why would base 2 be any different or base 7 or base 97?

We were taught to finish all the way at least to the decimal point and then depending on what year of school we were in we kept going after that
but at least in this case complete the ones column and then you can stop
for integer math.

10 goes into 34 3 times

```
     0123
   -----------
10 ) 1234
     12
    -10
    ---
      23
     -20
     ------
       34 
      -30
     ------
        4
```

This special math does not work differently.

1234 / 10 is 123 not 12.

0b10101 / 0b10 is 0b1010 not 0b101

### Edit 2

Somewhat easy to do programmatically

```
    ------------
abc ) defg...
```

Accumulator ra, Numerator rb, denominator rc, result rd

In grade school we were taught to handle one numerator digit at a time, the accumulator gets shifted left one by simply tacking the next digit on the right of it and then doing the test with the denominator again, each digit of the numerator gets a digit above it for the accumulator at that point in time.  So we start with an empty accumulator, we pull the ms digit off the numerator per iteration until we have exhausted ALL of the digits/bits not most of them.  So first loop is with bit d, second with bit e, third with bit f and so on until we are out of digits in the whole number numerator.

```
ra = 0;
rd = 0
For number of bits in the numerator:
  ra<<=1; //make room for next bit from numerator
  ra|=(rb>>(nbits-1))&1;
  rb<<=1; //prep for next loop
  rd<<=1; //make room for next result bit, fill with zero
  if(ra>=rc) // <-base 2 optimization either it is a 0 or 1
  { 
      rd|=1; //result for this bit is a 1 not zero
      ra-=rc; //subtract one times denominator from accumulator
  }
```

Something along those lines, I have validated C code that does this. Understanding that there are limits to the sizes of the numerator and denominator and other variables you want to say use 32 bit variables but keep the sizes of the numerator/denominator much smaller like your 10101 and 10.

Same as grade school math  1234/10

Start with an accumulator of 0 shift left and take the first digit

```
1 / 10 = 0 remainder 1  (10^3 column 1)
```

The remainder is the accumulator so take the next digit 2 shift 1 left and insert 2 making 12

```
12 / 10 = 1 remainder 2 (10^2 column 2)

23 / 10 = 2 remainder 3 (10^1 column 3)

34 / 10 = 3 remainder 4 (19^0 column 4)
```

So now we have covered all of the significant digits from 10^n to 10^0
thousands column to the ones column, that is the integer result.

So you can do that programmatically shift accumulator pull the next bit, compare accumulator with denominator, determine result for that power of the base, subtract off the accumulator, repeat until you finish the ones column or keep going if you want to go beyond the decimal/binary point.

### Edit 3 (fixed)

if you are doing a repeated subtraction thing

```
10101 - 10 = 10001  (1)
10011 - 10 = 10001  (2)
10001 - 10 = 1111  (3)
1111 - 10 = 1101  (4)
1101 - 10 = 1011  (5)
1011 - 10 = 1001  (6)
1001 - 10 = 111  (7)
111 - 10 = 101  (8)
101 - 10 = 11  (9)
11 - 10 = 1 (10)
```

Yes that is confusing the dividend needs to be zero or less perhaps.  I do long division that always works.

### Edit 4

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    unsigned int c;
    c = 0;
    while(a>b)
    {
       a-=b;
       c++;
    }
    return(c);
}
int main ( void )
{
    printf("%u\n",fun(21,2));
    return(0);
}

gcc so.c -o so
./so
10
```

### Edit 5

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    unsigned int c;
    c = 0;
    while(a>b)
    {
       a-=b;
       c++;
       printf("%u %u %u \n",a,b,c);
    }
    return(c);
}
int main ( void )
{
    printf("%u\n",fun(21,2));
    return(0);
}

19 2 1 
17 2 2 
15 2 3 
13 2 4 
11 2 5 
9 2 6 
7 2 7 
5 2 8 
3 2 9 
1 2 10 
10

#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    unsigned int c;
    c = 0;
    while(a>b)
    {
       printf("%u %u %u \n",a,b,c);
       a-=b;
       c++;
    }
    return(c);
}
int main ( void )
{
    printf("%u\n",fun(21,2));
    return(0);
}

21 2 0 
19 2 1 
17 2 2 
15 2 3 
13 2 4 
11 2 5 
9 2 6 
7 2 7 
5 2 8 
3 2 9 
10

#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    unsigned int c;
    c = 0;
    while(a>b)
    {
       printf("%u %u ",a,b);
       a-=b;
       c++;
       printf("%u \n",c);
    }
    return(c);
}
int main ( void )
{
    printf("%u\n",fun(21,2));
    return(0);
}

21 2 1 
19 2 2 
17 2 3 
15 2 4 
13 2 5 
11 2 6 
9 2 7 
7 2 8 
5 2 9 
3 2 10 
10
```

That was the problem with that, fixed edit 3.

```
10101 - 10 = 10001  (1)
10011 - 10 = 10001  (2)
10001 - 10 = 1111  (3)
1111 - 10 = 1101  (4)
1101 - 10 = 1011  (5)
1011 - 10 = 1001  (6)
1001 - 10 = 111  (7)
111 - 10 = 101  (8)
101 - 10 = 11  (9)
11 - 10 = 1 (10)
```

### Edit 6

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    unsigned int c;
    c = 0;
    while(a>b)
    {
       a-=b;
       c++;
    }
    return(c);
}
unsigned int fun2 ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    unsigned int res;
    unsigned int acc;
    unsigned int rb;

    res=0;
    acc=0;
    for(rb=0x80000000;rb;rb>>=1)
    {
        acc<<=1;
        if(rb&a) acc|=1;
        if(acc>=b)
        {
            acc-=b;
            res|=rb;
        }
    }
    return(res);
}
int main ( void )
{
    printf("%u\n",fun1(21,2));
    printf("%u\n",fun1(1234,10));
    printf("%u\n",fun2(21,2));
    printf("%u\n",fun2(1234,10));
    return(0);
}
10
123
10
123
```

Obviously you have limits on the sizes of things you cannot generically put any two values in and have these work.

Comment: But why do you check for the last iteration?

Comment: Okay! I understand the long division algorithm!!! But, what caused me to develop the wrong algorithm/ wrong code as seen above was the notion of Euclidean division that you need to *subtract till you make the dividend less than the divisor* How can I justify filling the slot of the ones place, in the *context* of Euclidean division algorithm! Thankyou very much in advance! Also, sorry for this very basic question!

Comment: dividend less than divisor?  you go until you are out of digits, less than or greater than is just part of the division process that is how you get 0 and greater than 0 digits in the result.

Comment: Okay so will it suffice to say, that we can run the second while loop while the **bitcount** difference between the aligned divisor and the original divisor is greater than or equal to zero!

Comment: This is not a homework question! This is something, that I thought I should put a lot of thought on. I am also trying to optimize/ make my code faster... If you look again at my previous algorithm, for binary division of 21 by 2, you could see that when I reached one, I had **nothing** to drop down from the numerator! But in your example of decimal division 1234 by 10 you **had** a **4** to drop down even when you got **3** as an intermediate remainder! :)

Comment: Please read my previous comment! I think I understand the long division process well, when it is done on pen-and-paper. I *realized* why you shift the quotient, is because when we reached the last iteration, you had a **1** to drop down and you need to divide that by 0b10  ...

Comment: *Please read my previous comment* Things become confusing, when we go from the pen and pencil world to the actual implementation, you will understand why, if you see my source code. In fact, every method should be consistent with Euclid's division, right? **Long** division is only an accelerated mode for traditional subtraction based division. But, no matter what, I liked your answer, very much, but still I am confused a little bit. I feel bad to ask these types of questions over here on stackoverflow! But sorry, I'm on my own on understanding several concepts! :)

Comment: please provide a or some references to what you mean by Euclidean division, I am simply seeing that a value divided by another can be represented by unique integers quotient and remainder.  how you get there doesnt seem to be Euclidean right?  Just that you can end up with a quotient and remainder.   Be it repeated subtractions or long division of which I demonstrated both.

Comment: in this case 10101 = 1010*10 + 1

Comment: sorry that I cant help you

Comment: spend more time on explaining your algorithm and either it will make sense to more of us or the process of explaining you figure out the issue.  Long division and subtraction make sense to me/most of us if you have something else then please describe.

Comment: Why we dont get the quotient = 10 when doing binary subtraction repeatedly as illustrated in the edit 3 of your answer?

Comment: Thankyou, very much, I think I fixed it. ! :)